# No module named 'matplotlip'

Tags: python

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlip.pyplot as plt
```

gives,

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlip'
```

I'm working with

> Python 3.6.5 (v3.6.5:f59c0932b4, Mar 28 2018, 16:07:46) [MSC v.1900 32
>   bit (Intel)] on win32

Use Python in shell as well as in Jupyter. 
The line >>> import matplotlip.pyplot as plt gives an error over and over again. Searching on the internet I found out that more people are having this porblem, however I could not find a solution. I've unistalled matplotlib and intalled it again. I used pip install as well as pip3 install. I've updated pip, etc, etc.
Does anybody know if there's a solution for this problem?

Comment: It's `matplotlib` ...

Comment: To be clear, you are ending the module name with the letter `p` but it should end with the letter `b`. The name is an abbreviation of "**mat**hematics **plot**ting **lib**rary," hence `matplotlib`.

Comment: This is what I call no research effort

Answer (score 1):

You need to use

```
import matplotlib.pyplot
```

matplotliB
NOT
matplotliP.